# storing current date time with milisec in varchar column - mssql

Tags: sql-server, date, varchar

*storing current date time with milisec in varchar column - mssql*

i do have a varchar max column 
i want to store current date with mili seconds in a column 
with Concatenating the `day-month-year-h-m-s-ms`

Like

```
2304201310151515
```

Comment: Why not use the built in [data types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms186724.aspx) that support `datetime` values?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever for a specific req

Comment: The problem is, you're storing a *formatted string* and not *data*. If you ever need to do any querying of this data, you'll almost certainly have to convert it *back* to a datetime data type. It would be far better to store the *data* in an appropriate datatype, and only apply formatting when displaying the data (or format it before passing it to a different system, if its an interop issue)

Comment: For this first of all varchar(max) is really a bad idea to use as data type.you can use varchar(20) is enough. I perfer using datetime and thats the best. IF you need more accurate seconds fraction then you can go for datetime2 in SQL server 2008. If you store date like what you are saying,it will affect the performance of the query looking for  a specific date and time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :-

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(max), getdate(), 103), '/', '')+
REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(max), getdate(), 114), ':', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME
SELECT @date = GETDATE()

SELECT 
    REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @date, 104), '.', '') + 
    LEFT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @date, 114), ':', ''), 8)

DECLARE @text VARCHAR(20)
SELECT @text  = '2304201310151515'

SELECT 
    CAST(
        SUBSTRING(@text, 5, 4) + 
        SUBSTRING(@text, 3, 2) + 
        SUBSTRING(@text, 1, 2) AS DATETIME) 
    + 
    CAST(
        SUBSTRING(@text, 9, 2) + ':' + 
        SUBSTRING(@text, 11, 2) + ':' + 
        SUBSTRING(@text, 13, 2) + '.' + 
        SUBSTRING(@text, 15, 2) AS TIME)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you use the varchar column for, but I highly recommend you use the yyyymmddhhmmssmmm format as it is sortable.

```
declare @date datetime = '20130423 10:15:15.15' -- Works in SQL 2008
select replace(replace(replace(replace(convert(varchar /* defaults to 30 char*/, @date, 121)
        , '-', '')
        , ':', '')
        , '.', '')
        , ' ', '')
```

Also, if you really want 2 digit milliseconds, then limit the characters returned from the convert function to varchar(22).

```
declare @date datetime = '20130423 10:15:15.15' -- Works in SQL 2008
select replace(replace(replace(replace(convert(varchar(22), @date, 121)
        , '-', '')
        , ':', '')
        , '.', '')
        , ' ', '')
```